# presentViewController above TabbarController

Tags: ios, swift

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let VC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyControlerVC") as! MyControlerVC

self.definesPresentationContext = true
VC1.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

self.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
// self.tabbarcontroller.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am trying to above code to show above Tabbar But I am showing this error. Please do not reply to use pushviewontroller. I need to tabar show

```
     ---> tabbarcontroller -> Cilck tababritem 
            --> UIViewcontroller --> Button Click --> Presnt aboveviewcontroller

 NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller
```

Comment: what you mean by Over TabbarController

Comment: `MyControlerVC` Already active or presented

Comment: On secondUIviewController of tabar i need to show presentviewontroller

Comment: VC1.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext i also this. No its' first time present than its showing error

Comment: are you sure that `MyControlerVC` is not your  `secondUIviewController`

Comment: Yes MyControlerVC is not tabbarcontrooler only  secondUIviewController is tabbarviewcontroler

Comment: where is you write this code , at second view controller or where